# dev_appserver.py can not link Go files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-go

I am trying to build my Go project for GAE and every once in a while running dev_appserver.py dev.yaml produces the following error

> /Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.8/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link:
>   /var/folders/82/3dqqxbqj7xgghyhnnk73qfc40000gp/T/tmpsdT41bappengine-go-bin/src/services.a:
>   not package main

Simply restarting works fine. For the life of me can't figure out why the linking fails.  Any ideas ?